# why does a for loop draw plots outside the loop and not in between the for conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, plot

I am trying to draw a plot inside a for loop and ask for input on whether the plot is correct or not and do other things before going to the next iteration. However, the plots only display after the loop has completed and thus doesn't allow for manual verification.

How do I make it display the chart in between iterations during the for loop?

example code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"TS":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                 "BOND":[54,34,54,56,34,12,34,56,78],
                 "ANGEL":[34,56,47,14,58,70,36,14,36],
                 "DIHED":[13,46,57,37,15,48,59,26,15]})

for col in df.columns[1:]:
    print(df.plot(x=col, y='TS'))
    answ = input('Input yes or no')
    #(do stuff about answ)
```

[image: Executing the loop gives the following]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Don't `print` the plot
- Add `plt.show()`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"TS":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                 "BOND":[54,34,54,56,34,12,34,56,78],
                 "ANGEL":[34,56,47,14,58,70,36,14,36],
                 "DIHED":[13,46,57,37,15,48,59,26,15]})

for col in df.columns[1:]:
    df.plot(x=col, y='TS')
    plt.show()
    answ = input('Input yes or no')
```

[image]